# How to replace part of one text field with a value from another text field in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to update a URL (in a text field) dynamically based on the user typing a value in another field.

Here's what I've got so far: http://jsbin.com/isiqus/10/edit

It works for the first trigger of the keyup event, but not on subsequent keyups. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong (I'm just getting to grips with jQuery).

Comment: see jsbin at http://jsbin.com/ojosag/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var valueTemplate = "http://{subdomain}.mydomain.com";
  $("input#alpha").keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("input#bravo").val(valueTemplate.replace("{subdomain}",value));
   });
});
```

It's going to keep a **template string**, that renders the other input field when the text is modified.

What was happening before was that you were **losing your original text** template in the first string replace.

Comment: +1 Nice approach. Although I guess the user should be able to alter the primary domain?

Comment: Thanks, this works great. What would be the technical term be for passing in the curly bracket as an argument (so that I can look it up and do a bit of learning)?

Comment: there is no need of curly bracket as an argument. you can see demo at http://jsbin.com/ojosag/edit#javascript
,html

Comment: Without complicating things too much, the curly bracket is a *delimiter* . It is used to specify the boundary of something. The use is mainly to avoid confusion say, if the domain template was `http://{subdomain}.whoneedsasubdomain.com` it would still work.

Comment: Hermant is right, there is no need for it strictly. You could have anything on that string. But it does serve as a delimiter, like I pointed in the above comment.

Comment: Jorgen raised a good point - what happens when you want to alter the primary domain?i.e. having two input values, one controlling the subdomain, the other the primary domain: http://{subdomain}.{mydomain.com}

I've spent the last 30 minutes trying but I'm too new to this to wrap my head around it. As soon as a try and alter {mydomain}, the input for subid returns to the original {subid}.

Comment: You could have a selector like `$("input#alpha,input#charlie").keyup` and in the replace clause two statements `$("input#bravo").val(valueTemplate.replace("{subdomain}",$("input#alpha").val());` and `$("input#bravo").val(replacedValueTemplate.replace("{domain.com}",$("input#charlie").val());` to replace both values every time any of the two change value.

Answer (score 2):

**v.replace("subdomain",value);**

statement contains error

first time when you call replace the string contains string subdomain but second time there is no strng like subdomain so it wont replace it.

refer http://jsbin.com/ojosag/edit#preview

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are trying to replace the string `subdomain` on `keyup`, which will get replaced on the first `keyup` event itself and is no longer valid for subsequent keyups

Comment: Ah I see, so on subsequent keyups there is no "subdomain" hence no argument hence nothing happens. Is there a method other than replace() I can use with values? Or a way of making replace() work? I'm a little bit stuck.

Answer (score 1):

By matching the pattern of the URL, you'll be good:

```
return v.replace(/http:\/\/(.*?)\./,'http://' + value +'.');
```

The pattern will match the first subdomain, so if the user adds more subdomains, the regex needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

on second `keyup` there is no `subdomain` substring in second text field

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("input#alpha").keyup(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("input#bravo").val(function(i,v){
    //return v.replace("subdomain",value);
    return v= "http://"+value+".mydomain.com";
   });
 });
```