# How to replace two parts of an input with values from two other inputs, in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a followup to the question I had answered (very satisfactorily) here:

[How to replace part of one text field with a value from another text field in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223757/how-to-replace-part-of-one-text-field-with-a-value-from-another-text-field-in-jq)

This answered how to update a subid in a link within an input.

I'm trying to extend this by having "mydomain.com" update from a second input:

http://jsbin.com/ojosag/3/edit

As soon as I try and change {mydomain.com}, I lose the {subid} part. Can anybody put me out of my misery?

Comment: Can you put your question into the question? It's just a bunch of links at present.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what Zero Distraction suggested for your original question, the following should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var valueTemplate = "http://{subdomain}.{domain}.com";
    var defaultSubDomain = "subdomain";
    var defaultDomain = "mydomain";

    var alphaOne = $("input#alpha");
    var alphaTwo = $("input#alphatwo");

    alphaOne.add(alphaTwo).keyup(function(){

        var value = (alphaOne.val()) ? alphaOne.val() : defaultSubDomain;
        var valueTwo = (alphaTwo.val()) ? alphaTwo.val() : defaultDomain;

        $("input#bravo").val(valueTemplate.replace("{subdomain}", value).replace("{domain}", valueTwo));

    });

});
```

When you start typing in either the first or second input, the value of the third will be updated. If either of the fields is empty, it will use the value of the `defaultSubDomain` and `defaultDomain` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. Probably could be made even more efficient.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var domainstr="http://subdomain.mydomain.com";
    $("input#alpha,input#alphatwo").keyup(function(){
        var alphaVal = $("input#alpha").val();

        var retVal = domainstr;
        if(alphaVal !== '')
          retVal = domainstr.replace("subdomain",alphaVal);

        var alphaTwoVal = $("input#alphatwo").val();
        if(alphaTwoVal !== '')
          retVal = retVal.replace("mydomain",alphaTwoVal);

        $("input#bravo").val(retVal);
     });
});
```